# Split path based on token to get path

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on project where main directory for code is prjcode.
some user will checkout code in home directory so their path will become `/home/shekhar/prjcode/src`

some may checkout code in any directory like `/home/shekhar/31jan/prjcode/src/`

Project need some scripts to run on prjcode path
how to find/extract path to prjcode/

`Input path- /home/shekhar/prjcode/src/  output path- /home/shekhar/`

`Input path- /home/shekhar/31jan/prjcode/src/  output path- /home/shekhar/31jan/`

`Input path- /home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/prjcode/src/  output path- /home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/`

please suggest.
Basically need path before prjcode directory .

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary delimiters, I often go with an awk solution:

```sh
$ paths=(/home/shekhar/prjcode/src/ /home/shekhar/31jan/prjcode/src/ /home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/prjcode/src/)

$ for path in "${paths[@]}"; do awk -F'prjcode/' '{print $1}' <<<$path; done
/home/shekhar/
/home/shekhar/31jan/
/home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/
```

And to unpack that into something very simple to read

```sh
echo "/home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/" | awk -F'prjcode/' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use `echo ${pth%"prjcode/src/"}` where `pth` is your path variable.

```
# pth="/home/shekhar/prjcode/src/"
# echo ${pth%"prjcode/src/"}
/home/shekhar/
#
# pth="/home/shekhar/31jan/prjcode/src/"
# echo ${pth%"prjcode/src/"}
/home/shekhar/31jan/
#
# pth="/home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/prjcode/src/"
# echo ${pth%"prjcode/src/"}
/home/shekhar/src_code/31jan/
```